# Dependency not found error in pom.xml in a maven project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I created a maven project.
It is getting an error because of this dependency in the POM file. 
**POM.XML**

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```

Project 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.2.0.RELEASE' not found. It gives error.
error description:
**Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.2.0.RELEASE from/to central**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: Typo?  Company firewall?

Comment: I am connecting from company computer. How do I know if there is a Software Error? @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Comment: Depends on the error.  Run maven from the command line.

Comment: thanks. solved  @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Comment: @island Now post a good answer for the next one with your problem to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.2enter code here.6.RELEASE</version>
<type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

**Note: Create Maven or anyone for spring using spring initializr(https://start.spring.io), so you will never face these kinds of problems**